# First project, powering an IC

Tags: low-power, led-strip

I am working on a RGB LED Strip controller to light the inside of my PC. I plan to use a Molex connection 12V DC to power the circuit, the LEDs I am using can run up to 12V, but it should run at about 9V. So I need to drop 12V - 9V for that.

In controlling the LEDs I have designed a system using 3 potentiometers and a HEX inverting Schmitt Trigger to control the LEDs values. The IC runs off of 2V - 5V and need to control power.

I designed the system by combining [this design](http://www.robotroom.com/PWM.html), and [this design](http://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips/usage), to power the LED strip and drop the power using a design I cannot find again.

(Note the LED in schematic is different from the ones actually plan to use, Ground in this case is meant to be +12V)

Before I go buy parts and start trying this, I want to get some better eyes on the project. I have yet to do anything other than messing around with an Arduino Uno and a breadboard to learn this stuff basically (I just figured how to use transistors as logic gates).

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Why bother dropping it down to 9v? The LED strips are designed for 12v, you have 12v. Why bother with the 3.3v regulator either? Your computer supply has 5v, the 74AC14 works on 5v. Hell you could also use the 3.3v off the ATX supply as well. Keep it simple.

Comment: And also, while analog design would work, you could jump right to using the Arduino (a microcontroller) to do this.

Comment: Bottom line I should forget about regulating the 12v and connect the 12v directly to the LED strip and the 5v to the IC from the Molex. And yes I know I can use the Arduino to do the same thing I made up, but I plan to use my Arduino for other projects, using the analog mode is prefereable. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes, using the existing 12v and 5v lines (both regulated) is preferred. Simpler, less parts, etc. The rest of the design seems proper though.

Answer (score 1):

In your circuit diagram is the first voltage regulator a 5V version and the second a 3.3V.

If you use a 7809 (9V) for the first and a 7805 (5V) for the second voltage regulator it should work fine. But have in mind the power consumption of the LED strip that the 7809 can handle it.

I don't know the PWM circuit with the 74AC14. If he post it it should work. But in your circuit you use 1N4001 diodes which is not necessary. They can handle higher current compare with the 1N914. Use the 1N914 or 1N4148 it is equivalent. [Datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf)